# lightning-record-edit-form Loading Default Values

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightning-record-edit-form that I am using for both new records and for editing of existing opportunities. (is that a best practice?) Is there a way to pass default values to the form when I click the "New" button?  I would like to populate an account lookup value on the opportunity to the community members account.  I have the community members account ID in a variable  (thanks to maniac coder) I know that I can set values so I can easily get the value of that broker to populate with the following:

```
<div class="slds-size--1-of-2">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Broker__c" value={BrokerAccountId}></lightning-input-field>         
</div>
```

Is there any way to add an if statement to the "value" so that it only uses the value if there is no current record ID?  Otherwise, If not, I could create a separate record edit form for new vs edit. I was hoping to avoid that.

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that a best practice?

This should be OK. (*I haven't seen any recommendation from Salesforce against this approach*)

> Is there a way to pass default values to the form when I click the
> "New" button?

You have already answered this in your question (& the code snippet). On click of new button, populate the fields/ properties that are wired to `lightning-input-field`.

> Is there any way to add an if statement to the "value" so that it only
> uses the value if there is no current record ID?

Use ***getters*** in your JS file to accomplish this. For example, retaining your HTML snippet as-is and assuming `recordId` as the field that stores current record ID, following should do the trick:

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'; // Declare this at the top of the JS file (i.e., outside the class)

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: [<Field API Name>]})
record;

get BrokerAccountId() {
    if(!this.recordId)
        return this._BrokerAccountId;
    else
        return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, <Field API Name>): "";
}
```

---

Another solution is to have conditional template based rendering (*include something like the snippet shown below within the `lightning-record-edit-form`*):

```
<template if:true={boolEdit}>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Broker__c"></lightning-input-field>
</template>
<template if:true={boolNew}>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Broker__c" value={BrokerAccountId}></lightning-input-field>
</template>
```

In the JS file, toggle the `boolEdit` & `boolNew` based on appropriate conditions (in your case, the presence of current record ID). ***Ensure that these boolean properties never become true at the same time (or false at the same time)***.

Comment: So which would be the direction you would go?  Would you create a separate form for edit vs new or would you keep one form and getters?  One more questions about using getters. If I open the field and there is an ID, would the code you provided overwrite the field is it was already populated?  thanks!

Comment: I would prefer using one form and getters (*although both approaches will work*). Could you elaborate a bit more on your second question (*did you mean you are trying to edit the field, did you mean for new record or edit record etc.*)? I've only given high level snippet for getter usage, but can be used to accomplish other scenarios too.

Comment: My concern was if I open an exiting record to edit, would this concept overwrite the existing field. I only want to write the broker field if this is a new record.  thanks!

Comment: The condition in my sample snippet [`(!this.recordId)`] was based on the assumption that presence of recordId means existing record (otherwise, a new record). So, in your case, instead of `return ''`, you can return the existing field value [*fetched using LDS*], if it at all the code overwrites the value. Note that if you use LDS, the wire service would execute much earlier in the component life cycle and the field values would be available when the getter is being called.

Comment: Another approach that I didn't mention earlier is to wrap the `lightning-input-field` inside 2 conditional templates [`<template if:true={<property>}></template>`], with 2 properties indicating new or edit form. So, at any given point of time, only one template will be visible and hence, only one input field. But, IMO, the getter approach is better.

Comment: I thought about the render approach but I was not sure if, even though a field was not rendered it would effect the save of the record. so if I have two version of the broker field, would the input field not rendering effect the save.  thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: If the conditional template evaluates to false, then that HTML content is removed from the DOM and hence, there will be effectively only one input field element. You can try querying for the input field using `querySelector` and you will find only one element. As long as you have taken precaution so that both templates don't evaluate to true, there should be no negative impact on the save. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it!!!!!